# Meaning of "Tay-Boy"

Tags: meaning, nineteenth-century-english

From *Vanity Fair* by William Makepeace Thackeray.

> Major O'Dowd, who had served his sovereign in every quarter of the world, and had paid for every step in his profession by some more than equivalent act of daring and gallantry, was the most modest, silent, sheep-faced and meek of little men, and as obedient to his wife as if he had been her **tay-boy**.

What's a "tay-boy". I couldn't find the word in my dictionary. Nor did a quick Google search yield any useful results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Major's wife is Irish,

> "Otherwise called Peggy, lady of Major Michael O'Dowd, of our
>   regiment, and daughter of Fitzjurld Ber'sford de Burgo Malony of
>   Glenmalony, County Kildare."

'tay-boy' is a representation of 'tea-boy' rendered to suggest the accent of County Kildare.

> "Sure, I couldn't stop till tay-time. Present me, Garge, my dear
>   fellow, to your lady. Madam, I'm deloighted to see ye; and to present
>   to you me husband, Meejor O'Dowd"

The use of 'tay' in the phrase 'tay-time' for 'tea-time' earlier in the section is probably intended to tip the reader off.

Comment: What's a *tea-boy*, though? Like the kid who brings in the tea service?

Comment: The question was 'what's a tay-boy', I answered that. I assume tea-boys to be general reference ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Accented speech in novels always trips me up. I think the worst case I've encountered so far was the character Jo in Bleak House. I had no idea what he was saying half of the time.

Comment: @DanBron During the British Raj in India (in which Major O'Dowd served) the British came into contact with a number of Indian servants with very specific roles often referred to as _wallahs_, examples are the _punkah wallah_ who operated a manual ceiling fan and the _dhobi wallah_ who did the laundry. One of these was the _char wallah_ or tea man. Given the tendency of people of higher status to call male servants (particularly those of a different race) 'boy' the char wallah could well become a tea (or tay) boy

Comment: @BoldBen And though *OED* doesn't mention the term *tea-boy*, there are a couple of uses to be found in Google books which show it was in use in the UK in the middle of the 19th century to designate a male domestic servant with duties similar to those of a housemaid, including laying and serving tea.

Comment: @StoneyB And that is even better. Sounds right to me!